# How to query nodes that have a version property with Cypher?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I've got nodes that represent Maven artifacts, e.g.:

```
CREATE (n:MODULE {artifactId:"com.my.test", version:"1.0.0"}) RETURN n.artifactId, n.version;
```

Someone got any idea how I could query for all nodes in the range of e.g. [1.0.0, 2.0.0]? I could also split up the version into three properties version_major, version_minor, version_micro, if that results in an easier query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are storing the version as a string then you can rely on the [lexicographical sort order](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/query-operators.html) for your query:

```
MATCH (n:MODULE)
WHERE n.version >= "1.0.0" AND n.version <= "2.0.0"
RETURN n
```